# How to read from this JSON file

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am new to android and JSON, but i am making a very simple app that should show data in a recycler view with the information given by a JSON file written like this:

```
{"server":"SuspServer","team":[{"name":"john","lastName":"doe"},{"name":"jane","lastName":"doe"}]}
```

and it gets the request for the infrmation like this:

```
val jsonRequest : StringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response->
        //Log.i("JSON", response.toString())
        val gson = Gson()
        val itemType = object : TypeToken<List<suspect>>(){}.type
        val suspects : List<suspect> = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), itemType)
```

My hunch (I noticed that error while writing this question) is that I am asking for a list of suspect objects that while it recieves Strings "name" and "lastName" as parameters cannot be recognized in the JSON, but I have no idea how to reference them in the format they are written like in the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to read the your json from resource :

```
// JSON data
fun Context.readJsonAsset(filename: String): String {
    val inputStream = assets.open(filename)
    val size = inputStream.available()
    val buffer = ByteArray(size)
    inputStream.read(buffer)
    inputStream.close()
    return String(buffer, Charset.defaultCharset())
}
```

```
data class MyClass(
    val server: String,
    val team: List<Team>
)

data class Team(
    val name: String,
    val lastName: String
)
```

and this method is sample to how read and set on your DTO example MyClass :

```
fun fetchJson(context: Context?): MyClass {
    val gson = Gson()
    val inputString = context?.readJsonAsset("database.json")

    return gson.fromJson(inputString, MyClass::class.java)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json structure represents a class looking like this:

```kotlin
data class MyClass(
    val server: String,
    val team: List<Team>
)

data class Team(
    val name: String,
    val lastName: String
)
```

So when you're deserializing, you can just give it the type:

```kotlin
val myDeserializedObject: MyClass = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), MyClass::class.java)
```